# Error copying waterfall charts with Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, graph, copy

I have some simple VBA code that loops through a range of graphs in my Excel workbook and copies them to a PowerPoint presentation. It works great for all graphs except for waterfall graphics (Error 445: “Object doesn't support this option”). Since they're relatively new to Excel, I thought there might be an issue of compatibility and was wondering if there was a workaround.

Thanks !!

```
'Bar chart ==> works fine
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(7).ChartObjects("Graphique 1").Copy
' Waterfall chart ==> Error 445
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(8).ChartObjects("Graphique 1").Copy
```

Edit: When I try to record the procedure with Excel's macro recorder, it gives me the same lines of code, but when executing the code, I get the same error.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 1").Activate
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Try to select the Chart (using `.Select`), and then`ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy`

Comment: Same problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with the waterfall chart and it does seem like VBA is not able to copy that type of chart.

Potential fixes:
You're able to copy as a picture using `.copyPicure` or you can make a workaround by using:

```
YourchartObject.duplicate.select
selection.cut
```

and then pasting to the Powerpoint.

Comment: If this answers your problem you can choose this as the answer to your post :)

Comment: I did but my reputation is insufficient for to publicly display my scores. Sorry.

Comment: I have a commercial VBA charting addin, which simply craps out when you try to copy a built-in waterfall chart to PowerPoint (it works fine with the custom waterfalls the software itself creates). I'll have to check out your proposed fixes.

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed a bit inelegant. But I've used workarounds which are much worse. Then I stumbled upon `Shapes("MyWaterfall").Copy`, which seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;** I stumbled on the following, which works for all charts, including waterfalls and other new Excel charts:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Any Chart").Copy
```

---

Here is how to copy most Excel charts:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("My Chart").Copy

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("My Chart").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
```

However, neither of the above work with a waterfall chart or other newer Excel chart.

If you record a macro while copying a waterfall chart, this is what you get:

```
Sub RecordedMacro1()
'
' Recorded while copying Waterfall chart
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Waterfall Chart").Activate
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

This also also does not work with a waterfall chart.

There's plenty of other tried and true chart-related VBA that doesn't work with the newer Excel charts.

Comment: Hi Jon, have you tried using `Sheets("your sheet").ChartObjects("your waterfall graph").Duplicate.Cut`? That’s what Mr ML suggested above. I’ve been doing this for months now and it works perfectly fine. I can copy all types of graphs to PowerPoint using that method.

Comment: Yes I did try that. It seems rather awkward, but it works. I was going to rework my routines to use Shapes("mychart").Copy, but then decided it was too much work. So now I check if it's one of the new charts and use .Duplicate.Cut. A minor change, really. Note I need to figure out how the copy a waterfall that's on a chart sheet.