# Can't find chart object despite having inserted one

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm just starting to work with charts in VBA. The manual seemed straight forward: All Charts are contained in Workbook.Charts and/or (well, not THAT clear for a beginner, as it turns out) Worksheets(x).ChartObjects. Only, I have now a graph in my workbook that I can not find in either collection.

Where is the object hiding?

I'm running a Little Marco, which should set the Colors of all Graphs according to my definitions. There are two Graphs in the workbook, on different spreadsheets. The second one (the one that is "vanished") is of type waterfall.

1. ?ThisWorkbook.Charts = 0.
2. ?ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph").ChartObjects.Count = 1
3. ?ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts").ChartObjects.Count = 0

Well the first two results are fine, the third should have been a 1 as well.

I doubt any code would be usefull - since I'm may just be looking in the wrong Corners?

What is a safe way, to cycle through all Charts in a workbook? Cycling over each worksheet's Charts in chartobjects doesn'T do the Job.

Why can I not find the Chart in the worksheet? Is this some specialty of waterfall?

I'm sorry if this may seem like a very basic question, I'm just starting into Charts.

Edit: Added the Loop:

```
Public Sub hrFormatAllCharts()
    Debug.Print ("hrFormatAllCharts: Enter")
    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ("Charts in worksheet " & ws.Name & " : " & ws.ChartObjects.Count & ".")
        For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects
            Call hrFormatChart(cht.Chart)
        Next cht
    Next ws
    Debug.Print ("hrFormatAllCharts: Exit")
End Sub
```

Bonus Point Question: Since I can see the Chart, is there a way through the GUI to ask the object "Where do you live?"?

PS: I verified that this issue is related to the Chart type (waterfall). I removed the waterfall and used another - now that other Chart is in the above collection. Deleted that one and put in again a waterfall: Can't find it in ChartObjects...

PPS: I found the following question in stack Overflow and now I wonder if it relates...: [Error copying waterfall charts with Excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198822/error-copying-waterfall-charts-with-excel-macro)

Comment: "I doubt any code would be usefull" - it definitely would.  Cycle over worksheets and then cycle over chartobjects in each worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams Well, see code above then. But I really think I'm just looking in the wrong place - is it possible that certain Charts are stored elsewhere? Otherwise I fail to see why the above code does not list the Chart.

Comment: I'm on Office 365 and ChartObjects.Count returns the expected vcalue with an inserted waterfall chart.  What Excel version/OS are you using, and how did you insert the "missing" chart?  Manually, or using a macro?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm using Excel 2016 on Windows 7 Enterprise. I added the Chart manually, not from script.

Comment: Change this `?ThisWorkbook.Charts` to `?ThisWorkbook.Charts.Count`. I assume you were just typing too quickly, but...

Comment: BTW, Waterfall and other new chart are not so well integrated into VBA. Things like counting them should be no big deal, but things like changing the chart title or various formats do not work.

Comment: @JonPeltier Yes, the .Count is not the source of the issue. Anyway, the third line should have been a 1 and it does include the .Count.

Comment: Put `Debug.Print "Calling hrFormatChart for cht.Name` in front of `Call hrFormatChart(cht.Chart)`. And BTW, no need to put the parens around the Debug.Print arguments.

Comment: What does `hrFormatChart` do, anyway? Maybe it's some of the things that VBA can't do with a waterfall chart. Do you have `On Error` commands that suppress what would be informative errors in the other procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Hey please find my proposition of looping through charts.

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()

Dim charts As ChartObjects
Dim chart As ChartObject
Dim sheetIterator As Integer
Dim loopSheet As Worksheet

For sheetIterator = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count()
    Set loopSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetIterator)
    Debug.Print loopSheet.Name

    Set charts = loopSheet.ChartObjects

    For Each chart In charts
        Debug.Print chart.Name
    Next chart


Next sheetIterator

End Sub
```

Comment: That seems dangerous: Mixing Sheet and Worksheet. These are different classes and and different collections, possibly resulting in different results of Counts. I wonder why there is no warning about loopSheet being defined as Worksheet but then it gets assigned a Sheet?

Comment: @YeOldHinnerk So I changed from Sheets to Worksheets, no big deal, now try it.

Comment: Well, still the same odd behavior. It doesn't Show the waterfall Chart in the list.